# why there is overlap of list when height properties is set in css?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

```
<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">

   ul{
      list-style:none;
      padding:0;
      margin:0;


   }

   li{
      float: left; 
      border: dotted 1px;
      line-height: 30px; 
      color:green;
      width: 100px;

      }
    ul li ul li{
    color:violet;
    width: 150px;

    }

</style> 
</head>
<body> 
<ul id="wow">
   <li>example 1</li>
   <li>example 2
      <ul><li>example1</li>
      <li>example1</li><li>
      example1</li></ul>
   </li>
   <li>example 3
   <ul><li>example1</li>
      <li>example2</li>
      <li>example3</li></ul>
   </li>
   <li>example 4</li>
   <li>example 5</li>
   <li>example 6</li>
   <li>example 7</li>      
</ul>   
</body>   
</html>
```

This is my code. My question is why when I set my height properties for list in css, there is a overlapping between the list and sub-list?how can I solve this

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by floating the list items to the left?

Comment: i wan to make a navigation bar

Comment: give `line-height:30px` instead of `height` in `li` CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sub ul list is child of main li that is y it is starting exactly after the li item. So Make that height as `line-height`.

```
    li{
      float: left; 
      border: dotted 1px;
      line-height: 30px; color:green
      }
    ul li ul li{color:violet /*write declaration for sub menu here*/}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UEMxg/4/)**

---

Hope this helps. Mouse over on the menu items to see the sub menu.

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/UEMxg/6/)**

Comment: but how if i want to make the example 2 and 3 (main list)smaller that it's sub list?

Comment: @dramasea check the updated answer. You can write different style for sub menu using ul li ul li{...}

Comment: @dramasea did u get it how sowmya is saying...........through this thing u can achieve your desired result.......

Comment: Thanks 4 helping me out, I already update my code, it seems like the sub list didn't float now, how can I make it flow?

Comment: @dramasea Check the updated answer. That is not modification of your code but I hope the second demo helps you out

Comment: yes, that exactly what i want, can u explain me how to make the sub list become like that? because obviously, the main list width is same as the sub list

Comment: or can u make a more simple version? i'm juz beginer of css

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code was that the sub items must be positioned relative to its parent.  for building a navigation bar try following :

```
 ul{
      list-style:none;
      padding:0;
      margin:0;          
   }

   li{
      float: left; 
      border: dotted 1px;
      height: 30px;
      position:relative;
   }

   ul li ul{
        position:absolute;
        top:100%;
   }
```

check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FPchT/).

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
li /* list and sub list */
{
  float: left; 
  border: dotted 1px;
  line-height: 30px; /* Instead of Height property */
}

ul>li>ul>li /* sub list */
{
   float: left; 
   border: dotted 1px;
   line-height:25px; /* give smaller height as you want */
}
```

To know more about CSS Selectors go through this **[Link](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorref)**.

Comment: it seems like the sub list didn't float now, how can I make it flow?

Comment: They should float.. may be there is some typo in your code.. let me check

Comment: @dramasea remove `width` you are making them of fixed width.. which are restricting the `Float`

Comment: can i make the main menu(list) which is example 2 and example 3 smaller?(and the) sub menu(list) bigger?

Comment: @dramasea yes giving different `padding` to them... Its not clear what you want actually.. please explain in brief in your question.